# Single or multiple calibration curves for interpreting datasets?

Tags: spectrophotometry

I ran three batches of samples through the HPLC. Each batch run contained standard solutions and a set of experimental samples. The standard solutions included in each batch run were exactly the same, but the experimental samples in each batch run represented different times the experiments were run. The composition of all of the experimental samples and the standards are exactly the same. I'm not sure what is the best practice for interpreting the the unknown concentrations in the experimental samples.

(1) Individual calibration curves: Should I interpret the experimental samples associated with a batch run with a calibration curve I make from the standards of that run?

OR

(2) Consolidated calibration curve: Could I make a single calibration curve using the responses from the standards across all three batch runs to interpret the experimental samples?

I can provide my data as an example. Thank you!

Comment: For serial analysis, there is often used calibration curve and regulation diagram based on control samples. The calibration curve is kept until regulation diagrams breaks the thresholds according given rules. Not sure if seriality applies in your case.

Comment: If there are isolated 3 sets, I would go rather for individual calibration curves. As involving standard solutions from all batches into a single curve could bring inter-batch bias errors.